# nginx location with unknown subfolder depth

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

I would like to have a custom location for images in order to set a better `expires` value and remove them from `access.log`.

The local path for an image would be sth like this `/var/www/html/public/image/user/{username}/{?subfolder}/filename.jpg`

There can be one or more subfolders where the image is located.

The url should look like `http://example.com/image/user/{username}/{?subfolder}/filename.jpg`. Since there can be different folders to `user` with a different folder depth, I cannot hardcode it.

I tried it with this location rule, but nginx tries to locate it in the default root and not in the specified one.

```
location /image/[^\\]+/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|ico)$ {
    root /var/www/html/public/image;
    expires           30d;
}
```

I tried the expression against a PCRE tester, and it was successful. Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `root` like in your example to `/var/www/html/public/image`, then a request to `/image/user/foo.jpg` will end up at `/var/www/html/public/image/image/user/foo.jpg` which is undesired. So I don't think you should touch `root` (it must stay pointed to `public` dir).

Simply:

```
location ^/image/.*/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|ico)$ {
    expires 30d;
}
```

will do the job.

If your filenames are somehow hashed/versioned (e.g. `foo.123.jpg`), you can use [`immutable`](https://github.com/GetPageSpeed/ngx_immutable) for aggressive caching:

```
location ^/image/.*/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|ico)$ {
    immutable on;
}
```